# Load list with content of object

Tags: python

I have an object that can't be dumped by `simplejson`, so I need to create a list from it first. Currently this is what I'm using:

```
    messages = h.flash.pop_messages()
    items = []
    for message in messages:
        item = {}
        item['category'] = message.category
        item['message'] = message.message
        items.append(item)
```

I feel like there is a more pythonic way for me to be doing this, can anyone shed some light?

**Edit:**

As requested, this is the class for the Message object:

```
class Message(object):
    """A message returned by ``Flash.pop_messages()``.

    Converting the message to a string returns the message text. Instances
    also have the following attributes:

    * ``message``: the message text.
    * ``category``: the category specified when the message was created.
    """

    def __init__(self, category, message):
        self.category=category
        self.message=message

    def __str__(self):
        return self.message

    __unicode__ = __str__

    def __html__(self):
        return escape(self.message)
```

Comment: Could you show us the class's code that's giving you a hard time?

Comment: It's from Pylons, and is the Message class from webhelpers.pylonslib

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
items = [{'category': m.category, 'message': m.message}
  for m in h.flash.pop_messages()]
```

Comment: Thanks Ignacio, that's exactly what I needed. I figured there would be some way to do it via list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, then simply get message to inherit from object

object provides a `__dict__` attribute which is a dictionary of all instance attributes of your object (and not class attributes or inherited attributes). Using this method will make your code less likely to break if you need to add more attributes to message later on.

```
class Message(object):

   classAttribute = None # will not feature in __dict__

   def __init__(self,category,message):
      self.category = category
      self.message = message

messages = h.flash.pop_messages()
items = [message.__dict__ for message in messages]
```

Comment: As an aside. Reconstruction of the message object should be really easy as well -- `m = Message(**messageDict)`